# Erro ao rodar app mobile react-native

Tags: javascript, java, mobile, react-native, cmd

Ao executar `react-native run-android` dá o seguinte erro:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 21.254 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Informações do JDK:

> java version "1.8.0_181" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build 1.8.0_181-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Informações do react-native:

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>   react-native: 0.55.4

Já tentei rodar no Genymotion, no próprio celular e no Android Studio, mas da o mesmo erro.

API 23 e 28.

Answer (score 2):

**Linux e MacOS**

Rode os seguintes comandos no terminal, ou salve-os dentro de um destes arquivos existente no sue sistema: ~/.bash_profile , ~/.profile ou ~/.zshrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Depois execute o seguinte comando:

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager  "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27" "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

Caso tenha dúvidas: https://github.com/Rocketseat/ambiente-react-native/blob/master/unix-android-sdk.md

**Windows**

Realize os seguintes passos deste tutorial: https://github.com/Rocketseat/ambiente-react-native/blob/master/windows-android-sdk.md

**Fonte:** https://github.com/Rocketseat/ambiente-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Caio, uma pergunta, está com a variável de ambiente ANDROID_HOME setada? Se não souber, rode o comando: `echo $ANDROID_HOME` **para mac ou linux**. 
Caso não tenha definido a variável, defina ela apontando para aonde está o seu SDK Android.

Caso esteja definido a variável, faça o seguinte:
Abra o Genymotion > Settings > ADB > Marque a opção **Use custom Android SDK tools** > Selecione a pasta que está definido o seu ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: Olá Thiago, não tinha a variável ANDROID_HOME, configurei todas as variáveis e ainda coloquei um caminho para o SDK no Genymotion, porém está dando os mesmo erro.

Comment: @CaioLucasTeixeiraF.O. quando você dá o comando android, ele identifica a variável?